# What is the mean of $\mu\sup u-u$?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, riemannian-geometry

As picture below, what is the mean of $\mu\sup u-u$ ?

Picture below is from  *Estimates of eigenvalues of a compact
Riemannian manifold* of Li and Yau.

> [image]

Comment: In the future it would be helpful to include the name of the book or the [context](https://books.google.com/books?id=-Y8DCAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA208&ots=UWClA9grcK&dq=%22let%20m%20be%20a%20compact%20manifold.%20if%20u%20is%20a%20solution%20of%20(1.1)%22&pg=PA208#v=onepage&q=%22let%20m%20be%20a%20compact%20manifold.%20if%20u%20is%20a%20solution%20of%20(1.1)%22&f=false).

Comment: @angryavian  Thanks , I have add it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$u$ is a function, $\sup u$ is the supremum of $u$. Thus $\mu \sup u - u$ should really be written $(\mu \sup u) - u$.